# SQL Server : get varchar version of column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I am trying to get the string representation of a column in my database using the fully qualified name.

So if I had a value like `server.dbo.table.id` it would return `id`. In C# you can use `nameof` to do exactly what I want to do.

Does anybody know of an equivalent T-SQL function?

Comment: Can you provide some context, is this inside a stored procedure? And what are you using the result for?

Comment: @user1840485 You or someone else will regret the day that you start littering your code with references to a specific instance and database. Why? An application goes through many different iterations over time as it evolves functionality - there will always be a need to have different versions of the application running at the same time - each using its own db instance and database. Be careful what you wish for. This also applies to the same version running against different databases for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the 'server' part of this server.dbo.table.id. Did you mean for the 'server' to be the database name?

If you can supply the full name in the form of schema.table.column, something like  **dbo.table.id** then you can query the info schemas in Sql Server using something like this

```
declare @full_name varchar(128); 
set     @full_name = 'dbo.Table1.ID'

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@full_name, 3)
AND    TABLE_NAME   = PARSENAME(@full_name, 2)
AND    COLUMN_NAME  = PARSENAME(@full_name, 1)
```

If you are using an older version of Sql Server then you will have to split the full column name.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not what your looking for, but this is a string way. the sys tables and information schema are good to find most things.

```
declare @fullly_qualified nvarchar(1024) = 'server.database.schema.table.column'
select right(@fullly_qualified, charindex('.',reverse(@fullly_qualified))-1)
/*
 sys views and old dbo options for discovery, not functions though for columns
 information_schema.columns is one, as mentioned above, others below
 */

select c.name, t.name, s.name
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
--or
select c.name column_name, o.name table_name, schema_name(o.uid) [schema] --schema_name funciton is only 2008 or later
from dbo.sysobjects o
inner join dbo.syscolumns c on c.id = o.id
where o.type = 'U'
```

Comment: This is really close to what I want to do. I would like to query the sys tables for the column, but I would like this part: declare @fullly_qualified nvarchar(1024) = 'server.database.schema.table.column' to be strongly typed. That way in my database project I will have a reference to the column and build would fail if that reference was broken.

Answer (score 0):

below is a query with resolution on most of the important parts in a sys.columns query. I'm sure there are a few datatypes I missed, just did it off the current db I'm working on.

```
select 
     c.name column_name
    ,type_name(c.user_type_id) type_name
    ,case 
        when type_name(c.user_type_id) in ('bit','int','bigint','datetime','datetime2','timestamp','date','text','ntext','uniqueidentifier','xml') 
            then type_name(c.user_type_id)
        when type_name(c.user_type_id) in ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar','varbinary','binary')
            then type_name(c.user_type_id) + '(' + iif(c.max_length = -1,'max',rtrim(c.max_length)) + ')'
        when type_name(c.user_type_id) in ('numeric','decimal') 
            then type_name(c.user_type_id) + '('+ rtrim(c.precision) + ',' +  rtrim(c.scale) + ')'
     end scripting_type_name
    ,c.max_length data_max_length
    ,c.object_id table_object_id-- the table object_id from sys.tables (alternatively 
    ,t.name table_name
    ,s.name schema_name
    ,@@servername + '.' + db_name() + '.' + s.name + '.' + t.name + '.' + c.name fifth_level_uncallable_in_sql --@@servername is sometimes inaccurate, serverproperty('MachineName') is direct and current.
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
```